# Retornar un error en una función estática

Tags: php

Estoy desarrollando un `Trait`, la cuestión que quiero en caso de que sea `false` si es posible retornar algún tipo de error informativo.

```php
  public static function esValido(valor){
    if(!is_null(valor)){
      return false;
    }
    if(!is_numeric(valor)){
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }
```

Por el otro lado

```php
 if(!miTrait:foo(valor)){
    echo "Valor inválido" 
 }
 echo "Valor válido"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución que encontré mientras redactaba la pregunta.

```php
 public static function esValido(valor){
    if(!is_null(valor)){
      new throw exception("Valor nulo!");
    }
    if(!is_numeric(valor)){
      new throw exception("El valor no es numérico");
    }

    return true;
  }
```

Por el otro lado

```php
try{
 miTrait:esValido(valor)
 echo "Valor válido"
}catch(Exception $e){
 echo $e->getMessage();
}
```